# Binding dataSet to listbox

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have two listbox's. One is filled by Users.

```
daUsers = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
daUsers.Fill(UsersLocal);
listBox2.DataSource = UsersLocal;
listBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox2.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Second is filled by documents. In document dataTable I'm storing same data wit UserID. 
Now I want to bind second list box with data from Document DataTable where UserID is from first ListBox. How I can do that? I tried by SQLCommand but it failed.

```
 daDocuments = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE UserID='listbox2.SelectedValue'", connection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string queryString = ("SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE UserID='" + listbox2.SelectedValue + "'";
```

Then use this `string` to assign data to your document `ListBox`.